# Simpler way to retrieve value from array

Tags: javascript, postman

Is there a simpler way to retrieve the value `"TestProject"` in the JSON response rather than using a for loop in my code?

```
[
    {
        "Id": "9ac44c1d-0066-47aa-a2a2-a9b90109b0a5",
        "Group": null,
        "DataFields": [
            {
                "Header": "ProjectID",
                "Value": "TestProject"
            },
            {
                "Header": "uui_ConfigPack",
                "Value": "75e8ce5a-7ae0-41ca-86f0-aca1e7158073"
            }
        ],
        "HasDocuments": null
    }
]
```

```js
var projResults = JSON.parse(responseBody);

var projNumber = 1;

dataProjectId = projResults[projNumber].Id;

projName = 'Not Found';
for (i = 0; i < projResults[projNumber].DataFields.length; i++)
    {
        if(projResults[projNumber].DataFields[i].Header == "ProjectID")
        {
            projName = projResults[projNumber].DataFields[i].Value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, there isn't a simpler way. Some library or helper function can help you if you need to repeat that logic but fundamentally all would be using some sort of iteration over the array

Comment: @vlaz yes there is, `find` method.

Comment: @SamiHult which is some sort of iteration over the array

Comment: But much simpler :) plus it will stop once it has found a match, which the original code doesn't.

Comment: @SamiHult still, it's fundamentally an `O(n)` operation in terms of complexity

Comment: @vlaz I think we are talking about different kinds of simplicity here. Original post was about "simpler way -- than using a for loop".

Comment: @SamiHult you are right, i was looking for a simpler way than using the for loop.

Comment: I know this ain't an appreciation forum, but seriously, thanks a lot for all the input...plenty of things to take away and read up on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use higher order functions like `map` `filter` `reduce` etc.
to avoid for-loops.

here is a 1 liner:

```js
var obj = [
    {
        "Id": "9ac44c1d-0066-47aa-a2a2-a9b90109b0a5",
        "Group": null,
        "DataFields": [
            {
                "Header": "ProjectID",
                "Value": "TestProject"
            },
            {
                "Header": "uui_ConfigPack",
                "Value": "75e8ce5a-7ae0-41ca-86f0-aca1e7158073"
            }
        ],
        "HasDocuments": null
    }
]

console.log(obj.map(i => i.DataFields).flat(1).find(i => i.Header === 'ProjectID').Value);
```

---

As stated by CertainPerformance and vlaz. This will lead to bad performance because of multiple iterations.

But if you like a declarative coding style you can use RxJS
in which you can do something like:

```
var obs$ = from(obj);
obs$.pipe(
  flatMap(i => i.DataFields),
  filter(i => i.Header === 'ProjectID' )),
  pluck('Value')
).subscribe(console.log);
```

which basically does the same thing but in a more performant way.

Comment: This constructs *two* unnecessary intermediate arrays *and* will throw an error if no match is found.

Comment: "a 1 liner" - that contains three distinct operations traversing the array each time. The fact that you *can* put all that in one line doesn't mean you *should*. Because if the amount of lines is your only metric, then any minifier will also turn an entire file into a single line, thus the code would be equally good.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to find an object in an array, for which the most idiomatic method to use is `Array.prototype.find`:

```js
var projResults = [
    {
        "Id": "9ac44c1d-0066-47aa-a2a2-a9b90109b0a5",
        "Group": null,
        "DataFields": [
            {
                "Header": "ProjectID",
                "Value": "TestProject"
            },
            {
                "Header": "uui_ConfigPack",
                "Value": "75e8ce5a-7ae0-41ca-86f0-aca1e7158073"
            }
        ],
        "HasDocuments": null
    }
];
var projNumber = 0;
const foundObj = projResults[projNumber].DataFields.find(({ Header }) => Header === 'ProjectID');
const projName = foundObj ? foundObj.Value : 'Not Found';
console.log(projName);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading about Array methods like:

- map
- filter
- reduce 
  ...
  the functions will help you manage your arrays in an efficient way, it will make your code looks cleaner, and easy to read, you will find more information about it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map

And i do suggest the 'javascript 30' of wesbos, he has a wonderful video about it :)